# What Chemical Database Extensions for Structure and Similarity Search are there?

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics, databases

I am looking for extensions/add-ons for relational databases (RDBMS) that enable storing and handling chemical structures including the possibility for substructure searches and similarity search.

I am currently dealing with a custom application that is built on top of an Oracle 11gR2 database with the [*OrChem*](http://orchem.sourceforge.net/index.html) extension. In the words of the accompanying [scientific publication](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-2-S1-P28), *OrChem* is

> [..] an extension for the Oracle 11G database that adds registration and indexing of chemical structures to support fast substructure and similarity searching.

This is what the application needs.

The problem is that *OrChem* does not seem to be maintained anymore, the  [last release happened almost 10 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orchem/files/). From what little I could find in my research, I got the impression that *OrChem* also only seems to play nice with Oracle 11G, which will soon reach the [end of its extended support lifecycle](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2068368_1.html).

So, since I have the need to upgrade the underlying database, I am looking for information on alternatives (or, if someone can offer, experiences with running *OrChem* with versions >= Oracle 12).

For possible alternatives, projects that I could find are

- [*MyChem*](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mychem/), an extension similar to *OrChem* for the MySQL database (versions >= 4.0) and MariaDB. Of the projects I could find, this one is the least outdated, but even that means that the [last release happened 6 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mychem/files/).
- [*Pgchem::tigress*](https://github.com/bgruening/pgchem_tigress), a cheminformatics extension for the PostgreSQL DBMS (version > 8.x). Similarly to *OrChem*, the [last commit happened almost 10 years ago](https://github.com/bgruening/pgchem_tigress).
- [*chemsearch*](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chemsearch/), for which again, the [last release happened about 10 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chemsearch/files/). This one seems to be relatively mature (version number is 3.2) and it supports at least the Oracle and PostgreSQL RDBMS, the source code zip also has folders named `mssql` and `mysql`. However, since I could not find a real documentation, I am unsure which versions of the different RDMBS are actually supported.

Can anyone offer deeper insights concerning the compatibility of the listed cheminformatics extensions with concrete RDBMS versions and/or more current alternatives that are not listed here?

Comment: You do not specify the type of molecules.  If these are small and deposit as SMILES strings, you may consider to compute *fingerprints* for a subsequent *similarity search*.  See, e.g., this entry from the [OpenBabel documentation](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fingerprints/fingerprints.html#similarity-searching), or Greg Landrum's presentation at RDKit user group meeting 2012 [here](https://www.rdkit.org/UGM/2012/Landrum_RDKit_UGM.Fingerprints.Final.pptx.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that my search was missing the correct keyword. The database extension modules I was looking for are usually called **cartridges**.

A search for *rdbms chem cartridge* yielded a few more recent options:

- [Bingo](https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/bingo/index.html) (open source, for Oracle, PostgreSQL and MSSQL Server)
- [RDKit PostgreSQL cartridge](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cartridge.html) (open source, for PostgreSQL)
- [JChem Cartridge for Oracle](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/jchem-cartridge-for-oracle.md) and [JChem PostgreSQL Cartridge](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/jchem-postgresql-cartridge.md) (commercial, for Oracle and PostgreSQL)
- [MolCart](https://www.molsoft.com/molcart.html) (commercial, for MySQL)

This list is not meant to be exhaustive, just thought I'd share what I could find already with little effort.

Comment: Just ran into NextMove's Arthor: https://www.nextmovesoftware.com/arthor